# Vim: delete object files on save?

Tags: vim

Lets say I'm working on the file src/MyString.c, when I save I want vim to delete src/MyString.o and src/MyString.debug.o or better src/MyString.*.o.

How do I configure this in my .vimrc? Thanks

Comment: Why is your makefile not handling this?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? If I don't delete the object then the makefile expects that it's not changed and won't compile it...

Comment: Then you've goofed up your makefile.

Comment: Can you at least provide an example of what your talking about rather than just saying "your doing it wrong"

Comment: You forgot to specify that the object files are dependent on the source files.

Comment: The last few lines: https://bitbucket.org/chancey/eagle/src/f04192896790e4f147d0f051d926eafd247be054/Makefile is that the correct way to do the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I, too, think that you shouldn't need this and that your Makefile should be able to take care of the issue. But until you correct your Makefile, this might help:

```
function! RemoveObject()
    let objectfile = substitute( expand( '%:p' ), '.c$', '.o', '' )
    let rmcommand = "rm -f " . objectfile
    let error = system(rmcommand)
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePost *.c call RemoveObject()
```

Comment: Two errors here: 1. substitute(, '.c$',,) will work on any file ending with `c` (dot means “any character” and with `%:p` there will additionally be at least directory separator) and 2. you must use shellescape. The whole thing can be easily written in a three lines with `autocmd! BufWritePost *.c :silent! call delete(expand('<afile>')[:-3].'.o')` as a second (first and last should be `augroup RemoveObject` and `augroup END`). Note: no `rm -f` and shellescape, vim has built-in function for deleting files.

Comment: Wow. Some very cool advice there, ZyX. Thank you! Where can I find documentation for `[:-3]`? I've never seen this, have an idea of how it might work and would like to learn more.

Comment: Ah! Found it. For anyone interested, try `:help expr-[:]`